# CSS center element with absolute position on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, center, absolute

Alright, so I have a problem with centering an element. I've got a div that is 2300px wide:

HTML

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

CSS

```
#myDiv { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%; margin: 0 0 0 -1150px;}
```

And this works great in every browser except iPad Safari. Does anyone know how to work around this issue?

Regards, 
David

Comment: Does it's parent Div also have a fixed width? Is so then you could set the left property exactly in pixels. E.G. If it's parent Div was 2500px then you could set left:100px on 'myDiv'.

Comment: it's parent div is a body tag

Comment: Have you tried putting position:relative on the body tag? Not sure if it's required but maybe iPad Safari requires it.

Answer (score 0):

Does the div need to be absolute positioned?

If not, you can just use `margin: 0 auto;`

Also, try defining a width.